# -est vs. -st verb endings in Early Modern English

Tags: verbs, early-modern-english

I've been Googling for a little while tonight, but I can't seem to find any rules on this.

Irregular ("strong") verbs seem to be pretty set in their endings: goest, dost. But when I get to something like "bring", it seems almost like "bringst" and "bringest" are equally valid, and I can't find any examples to lead me to one sort of rule or another. If anyone could shed some light on this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: (1) spelling was still pretty irregular and personal in EME. (2) there is no real difference between _-est_ and _-st_ endings in EME; the vowel is placed there at the whim of the speller, since the _e_ was unstressed and often not pronounced at all. (3) the 2sg verb inflection was /-st/ after vowels and resonants, with an epenthetic vowel inserted to break up unruly clusters with some verbs. Thus _bring_ ends in a resonant, and /brɪŋst/ is not hard to pronounce, while a verb like _cost_ probably needs epenthesis. (4) there was a lot of variation -- often political -- about using 2sg suffixes.

Comment: @JohnLawler Please post as answer.

Comment: It's not spelling irregularity, per se, it is verb tense.

Answer (score 3):

John Lawler posted this answer as a comment:

> 1. Spelling was still pretty irregular and personal in EME.
> 2. There is no real difference between *-est* and *-st* endings in EME; the vowel is placed there at the whim of the speller, since the *e* was unstressed and often not pronounced at all.
> 3. The 2sg verb inflection was /-st/ after vowels and resonants, with an epenthetic vowel inserted to break up unruly clusters with some verbs. Thus *bring* ends in a resonant, and /brɪŋst/ is not hard to pronounce, while a verb like *cost* probably needs epenthesis.
> 4. There was a lot of variation — often political — about using 2sg suffixes.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that spelling would be erratic, kinda like, you don't spell it, son, you just say it! But in the case of *bring* I think it's more about they type of resonant that allows for the variation of the two endings. The fact that it ends in a *nasal* and therefore no occlusion in the oral cavity, both endings are easily pronounced.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Older English.

That being said, it is not a matter of irregular spelling, it's a matter of verb conjugation.

- First person singular: I bring my sword and a potato salad!
- Second person singular: Bringest thou my sword, Dudley?
- Third person singular: He bringeth my sword, Dudley.

Where you see -st instead of -est, this is merely a shortened form, a contraction, if you will.

Unless you are allergic to the Bible as literature, I suggest you do some reading in the King James Version.  You will see how that venerable volume uses conjugation properly.

Comment: Inflectional differences between persons (1st vs 2nd vs 3rd) are not matters of “tense”.

Comment: OK, conjugation then.

Comment: Don't use the word "properly". The language has simply gotten rid of those endings, and it would now be *improper* to use them unless you were attempting to imitate eMnE or Biblical English.

Comment: What?  You think I use EME in my daily walk?  I don't.  If one wants to use it, properly as opposed to sloppily, then what I wrote is the proper use of it.